# Defining a task color for each row in Angular-Gantt

Tags: angularjs, gradient, gantt-chart

I am using angular-gantt to represent  a series of tasks and I would like to have the tasks of a specific row with a specific color.
To add to this I have added the modules gantt-movable and gant-draw-task.

I know how to fix the color of a task at the start but not how to modify it according to the row in which the task is in.

Thank you for any pointers.

EDIT:

Ctrl

```
    (function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('Dashboard.pages.devices.planning')
    .controller('PlanningGanttCtrl', PlanningGanttCtrl);

function PlanningGanttCtrl($scope,$sessionStorage) {


    $scope.data=$sessionStorage.planning[$scope.dayNumber];


    $scope.headersFormats = {
        day: 'D',
        hour: 'H',
        minute:'HH:mm'
    };


    $scope.data = [
        {name: '20°C', tasks: [
            {name: '', color: '#F1C232', from: new Date(2013, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0), to: new Date(2013, 10, 5, 6, 0, 0) }
        ]},
        {name: '19°C', tasks: [
            {name: '', color: '#F1C232', from: new Date(2013, 10, 5, 7, 0, 0), to: new Date(2013, 10, 5, 10, 0, 0)}
        ]},
        {name: '18°C', tasks: [
            {name: '', color: '#F1C232', from: new Date(2013, 10, 5, 10, 0, 0), to: new Date(2013, 10, 5, 12, 0, 0)}
        ]},
        {name: '17°C', tasks: [
            {name: '', color: '#F1C232', from: new Date(2013, 10, 5, 12, 0, 0), to: new Date(2013, 10, 5, 15, 0, 0)}
        ]}
    ];

    $scope.drawTaskFactory = function() {
        var newTask = {
            id: 5,
            name: 'New Task'
            // Other properties
        };

        return newTask;
    }
}
})();
```

Html

```
<div gantt data=data headers="['hour']" headers-format="headersFormats" task-out-of-range="expand" expand-to-fit="true" >
    <gantt-table></gantt-table>
    <gantt-movable></gantt-movable>
    <gantt-tooltips></gantt-tooltips>
    <gantt-resize-sensor></gantt-resize-sensor>
    <gantt-draw-task enabled="true" task-factory="drawTaskFactory" move-threshold="4"></gantt-draw-task>
  <gantt-overlap enabled="false" global="true"></gantt-overlap>
</div>
```

And the directive even if I don't believe it is useful,

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('Dashboard.pages.devices.planning')
    .directive('planningGantt', planningGantt);

/** @ngInject */
function planningGantt() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'PlanningGanttCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/devices/planning/planningGantt/planningGantt.html',
        scope: {
            dayNumber: '=info'
        },
    };
}
})();
```

Comment: can you provide the code html/js of your case?

Comment: @shershen see edit

Answer (score 0):

Is the colour and other data of the current column in which task is - is known to you? 
Then you could use event system to change colour property of the task, when it's moved. It may look approximately like this:

```
//in single task directive's controller
data = {
  id://column id
  color: //column color
};
$scope.$emit('taskChangeEvt', data);

//in PlanningGanttCtrl
$scope.$on('taskChangeEvt', function(event, eventData){

  $scope.data.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.id == eventData.id){ //find task that fit that column by ID
    //update that task's colour
    item.color = eventData.color;
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea, i'll try it out and tell you what happens

Comment: Ok, so my problem it actually catching the move event, documentation says that api.tasks.on.moveEnd(task) should tell me when a task is moving but should I do this for all tasks ?